# Spring Cloud API Gateway Passing Dynamic Parameter value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, api-gateway

I'm learning how to build an API Gateway using Spring Cloud. I've scoured through the documentation on how to pass a parameter and all examples seem to show them as hardcoded in. But what if I have a dynamic value?

For example I have this type of request: http://localhost:8080/people/lookup?searchKey=jdoe,

How do I pass in the "jdoe" part?

I tried the following code and it works only if I hardcode the value in the code.
i.e., `.filters(f -> f.addRequestParameter("searchKey",  "jdoe")` .
That test also proves that my discovery server (Eureka) is working.

I'm not sure how to access the value using the provided builder methods. It's such a simple scenario but I'm surprised to find out there's not a lot of example or documentation for it so it must be just me.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("people-service", r -> r.path("/people/active-associates")
                        .uri("lb://people-service"))
                .route(r -> r.path("/people/lookup")
                          .filters(f -> f.addRequestParameter("searchKey",  howDoIPassDynamicValueHere))
                          .uri("lb://people-service")
                          .id("addrequestparameter_route"))
                .build();
    }
```

This obviously worked when I call the service directly because my microservice controller handles it like this using the @RequestParam...pretty straightforward:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/people")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    /**
     * Searches by FirstName, Lastname or NetworkId.
     * 
     * @param searchKey
     * @return ResponseEntity<List<Person>>
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "/lookup")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> findPersonsBySearchKey(@RequestParam(name = "searchKey") String searchKey) {
        List<Person> people = personService.findActivePersonsByFirstLastNetworkId(searchKey.trim().toLowerCase());
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Person>>(people, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    }
```

Comment: It should automatically pass all request parameters

Comment: What would your dynamic value be? Where would it come from? It’s a route mapping - it’s resolved at configuration time.

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Boris the Spider, the dynamic value is well dynamic..it will be coming from the client..so it's user typed. So for example I have a search bar in my UI client and the user types in a value, I call the API and pass the value so my service can do a search using that parameter value. Are you saying this type of requests will not work via route mapping?

Comment: I’m saying that those types of values are irrelevant to route mapping! Query parameters, headers etc will be passed through - it’s a proxy after all. Route mapping is to decide _where_ to pass them! If, for example, you wanted all searches prefixed with `person` to go to `personservice` and all searches prefixed with `animal` to go to `animalservice` then you would add a route mapping with “hard coded” as you say, values. To pass through a parameter nothing is needed.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks. It makes sense now. Modified my code and posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, it started making sense to me. I guess I did overthink when I read the documentation about the filter's addRequestParameter() method. I thought that I would need to use that method if my requests have parameters. Been scratching my head for a day and I can't believe it's that simple. So I got it working by just removing that filter:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("people-service", r -> r.path("/people/active-associates")
                        .uri("lb://people-service"))
                .route(r -> r.path("/people/lookup")
                          .uri("lb://people-service"))
                .build();
    }
}
```